# Flot Radius of hover point

Tags: jquery, flot

Flot shows when hovering over a data point there is a transparent expanding of that point shown. e.g. take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/UtcBK/embedded/result/

Is it possible to modify this hover effect? I don't want the radius of it that big.

```
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. I checked out the drawPointHighlight function as Ryley mentioned and found that Flot calculates the radius using the following formula:

```
var pointRadius = series.points.radius + series.points.lineWidth / 2;
```

To be able to control the radius without having to edit the plugin itself, you can specify a radius in the options as such (I removed the other options for clarity):

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),[d], {
           series: {
               points: { radius: 1 }
           }
         });
```

This means however that you'll be controlling the size of the point itself. Hope this helped.

http://jsfiddle.net/neQUt/

Answer (score 0):

Change the radius form the point series, that will affect also the radius of the hover itself.

Something like this:

points: { radius: 1 }

Answer (score -1):

You cannot control this, unless you are willing to edit the source code of flot.  The relevant area in Flot 0.7 is the function `drawPointHighlight`.  You'd likely want to change the `radius` variable...